# Error: Failed to lookup view -> simple code

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I want compile a jade file with dynamic content.
My code is from here http://jade-lang.com/tutorial/ :

```
app.get('/test', function(request, response){

var fn = jade.compileFile('views/test.jade');
var htmlOutput = fn({
  maintainer: {
    name: 'Forbes Lindesay',
    twitter: '@ForbesLindesay',
    blog: 'forbeslindesay.co.uk'
  }
});
response.render(htmlOutput);
});
```

I get the error below:

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><h1></h1>Maintainer: Forbes L
        indesay</html><table><tr><td>Twitter</td><td>@ForbesLindesay</td></tr><tr><td>Blog</td><td
        >forbeslindesay.co.uk</td></tr></table>" in views directory "D:\test.js\views" "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><h1></h1>Maintainer: Forbes L
        indesay</html><table><tr><td>Twitter</td><td>@ForbesLindesay</td></tr><tr><td>Blog</td><td
        >forbeslindesay.co.uk</td></tr></table>" in views directory "D:\test.js\views"
```

It seems to be that the variables are correct (taken from the route.js).
What does the error mean? There are a few questions like mine, but I cannot adapt it to my scenario...

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have any code that sets the view paths? `app.set('views', __dirname + '/views')`

Comment: my code `app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));`

Comment: You could use `response.status(200).send(htmlOutput);` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to mix the standalone method of rendering Jade templates with the ability of Express to render them for you.

Try this:

```
app.get('/test', function(request, response) {
  response.render('test.jade', {
    maintainer: {
      name: 'Forbes Lindesay',
      twitter: '@ForbesLindesay',
      blog: 'forbeslindesay.co.uk'
    }
  });
});
```

Make sure Express is configured properly, though. In your Express setup, use this:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

This assumes that the `views/` directory is a direct child of the .js file where you're calling `response.render()` from. More information [here](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-template-engines.html).

If you really want to use `jade.compileFile()` instead, you can use the suggestion in the comment made by @ArtemBaranovskii and use `response.send(htmlOutput)`.

Comment: its not possible to store it in a variable and then render it? the reason for my testcode is to learn how to use jade.compileFile for a more complex code...

Comment: I think it would work, but then you would need to use `response.send(variable)` and not `response.render`.